# Problems with a customize email in a google form html notification (href attribute)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I designed a code for google form notification to gmail. I tried to put a html url in the notification, but i don't know how to put a href attribute in the body message

I defined a variable with  urls direction but it seems to me too long for the notification.
Here's the section
  // DETALLES DE CORREO //

```
 // la dirección de correo a quien se le envía la notificación
var emailRecipients = correo_owner;
 //url del formulario de aprobación
var urlform = "my google form's URL+=unique_number&entry_735844299="+id+"&entry_1879717573="+val_tipo+"&entry_1369722885="+email;

  // Asunto del correo
 var emailSubject = "Ingreso de registro de no conformidad/oportunidad de 
mejora n° "+id+" por " + email ;
```

// Body

```
 var emailBody = "<h3>Ingreso de registro reportado por "+nom+":</h3><hr 
     /> \
     <p> \
     <h3 style='line-height:70%'>Ingreso de No conformidad/oportunidad de 
     mejora <br /> \
     <span style='font-size:50%'>("+fecha+")</span></h3> \
     </p><hr /> \ <p> \
     <strong>Tipo de reporte:</strong><br /> \
     "+tipo+" \
     </p>\ <p> \
     <strong>Origen de Hallazgo:</strong><br /> \
     "+origen+" \
     </p> <p> \
     <strong>Descripción de 'No conformidad':</strong><br /> \
      "+conform+" \
     </p> \ <p> \
     <strong>Descripción de Oportunidad de Mejora:</strong><br /> \
     "+oport+" \
     </p>\ <p> \
    <strong>División:</strong><br /> \
    "+div+" \
    </p>\ <p> \
   <strong>Sección:</strong><br /> \
    "+section+" \
 </p>\ <p> \
 <strong>Favor aprobar, rechazar o derivar el requerimiento en el 
 siguiente link:</strong><br />\
 "+urlform+"\
  </p>"   ;
```

I need to get a method to put the url on a href attribute in the body' message. I tried to put a "href" attribute on the html body instead of var "urlform" but it won´t result
Can you help me please?

Comment: Add `<a href="+url+">text of message</a>`?

Comment: yeah, that. I tried to put the attribute in the body in html format but i won't  had results

Comment: Show that in your code instead of unnecessary fluff. Provide [mcve]

Comment: @LuisOrrego Please edit your question to show a more narrow section of code where the issue is, otherwise we can only guess where the problem is.

Comment: @AMolina i change the post. Done!